# mocha conditional data driven testing

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I want to execute same test cases multiple times in mocha and number of execution condition will  be set in before code block of test.

Here's my sample code:

```js
describe('describe block ',function() {
    var a;
    
    before('before hook', function () {
        a =[1,2,3,4];
        console.log('outside before '+allorders);
    })

    a.forEach(()=>{
       it("Check it", function () {
          console.log('HI');
       });
    });

});
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: why do you want to run same thing more than once? Will the test logic depend on array value? Also please add what is the current problem with your code.

Comment: requirement is run test cases as number of row present in webpage.

Comment: This is not an answer to all 2 of my questions, and 1 request

Answer (score 0):

Now what I would do is wrap my test into a function and then run that test with the input. a very simple example would look like this

```js
const { expect } = require("chai")

const myTest = (input) => {
  it('will do something with the input', () => {
    expect(input).to.be.true;
  });
}


describe('all my tests', () => {
  [true,false,true].forEach(val => {
    myTest(val)
  })
});
```

If you want to set the array in the before block this would look like this

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");

let testCases;

const myTest = (input) => {
  it('will do something with the input', () => {
    expect(input).to.be.true;
  });
}


describe('all my tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    testCases = [true, false, true];
  });

  testCases.forEach(val => {
    myTest(val)
  })
});
```

In this case the test would be run 3 times and check if the input is true. So it would pass on the first and last go and fail on the second. It's a pretty trivial example but I think it clarifies how you can accomplish what you want to do

Comment: my scenario is array value to run time set. This won't work for me

Comment: you can easily do this in the before block as well. I will edit the answer to make it easier to read. Hope this is what you meant otherwise you may need to elaborate a bit more on your problem

Comment: getting following Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined for testCases.can you please try same from your side

Comment: Ah yes. I see my error. Will update the answer when I get back to the pc